# magento 2.1 header is visible on checkout page

Tags: magento-2.1, header, footer, checkout-page

I am working on **Magento 2.1.10**. **Header and footer are visible** at my **checkout page**. I don't know where I am wrong.

One thing that I can confirm is I did't override any checkout layout file to display the header and footer on the checkout page.

Please guide to fix this.

Comment: Are you using any pre-built theme?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Yes, We are using one. It was not visible earlier but all of sudden it starts appearing on checkout page.